# Want to have image rollover (1st hover state) to hover with background image in 2nd hover state

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, image

I have these following code in which I want to enable 2nd hover state applied to the button that is placed on 1st hover state on the certain box div - so when a user hovers a box div, the button appears in 1st hover state, then when the user hovers that button in the box div or span element, the button changes in 2nd hover state to be bright in appearance.

Can this be possibly done and accomplished easily? I have used Jquery and DOM but it did not work.

HTML:

```
<div class="product"><a href="#"><span><img src="images/more-details.png"/></span><img src="images/product.jpg" width="220" height="195" alt="product"/></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.product{width:220px; height:195px; float:left; margin-right:18px;margin-bottom:24px; position:relative; }

.product span{width:220px; height: 195px; position:absolute; visibility:hidden; background: url("images/more-details.png") no-repeat;}

.product span a{width:220px; height: 195px; position:absolute; visibility:hidden; display:block; overflow:hidden; background: url("images/more-details.png") no-repeat;}

.product span a:hover{width:220px; height: 195px; position:absolute; visibility:hidden; display:block; overflow:hidden; background: url("images/more-details-over.png") no-repeat;}

.product span:hover{visibility: visible;}

.product span.show{visibility: visible;}.product span.hide{visibility: hidden;}

.product span img{visibility: hidden;}

.product span img showimg{visibility: visible;}
.product span img hideimg{visibility: hidden;}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".product").hover(
            function() {
                 $(this).find('span').toggleClass('show');
            }, 
             function(){ 
                $(this).find('span').toggleClass('hide');
             }
         );
         $(".product span").hover(
            function() {
                 $(this).find('img').toggleClass('showimg');
            }, 
             function(){ 
                $(this).find('img').toggleClass('hideimg');
             }
         );
```

Comment: Did you try to do the `$("product span").hover` outside the first hover, because I'm not sure whether you can chain that this way !? Also a little suggestion, when you're saying `xy didn't work`, describe what didn't work and why!

Comment: Hi Dan @DanSurfrider, thanks for your comment. Regarding the what "didn't work" question, I meant that the <img> tag needs to be always inside the div then when the <img> tag is hovered, then a <span> element or similar element (a button appearing above image) would show in above that image, then again, when the <span> is hovered, the button changes to its own hover state - in other words changes to bright colour in the button. I assume this button can be contained within span element in highest zindex above the image (which embedded inside .product div).

Comment: @DanSurfrider one more thing, I had wanted to use the code as above in the Wordpress ecommerce so that is why JQuery is needed to add span and make the button hover for each product image that is dynamically generated and inserted into the "page". Because every time I add new product in wp ecommerce, the product image would appear in <img> tag in the page, but I am not sure how to make the button in 1st hover of the product image to change its own button over state (in 2nd hover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think you need jQuery to achieve your goal: http://jsfiddle.net/z6sgY/1/

Comment: Thanks ptriek for that. You are almost correct in understanding the question, however, what I wanted in the product hover is that the product div needs to have an <img> tag inside rather than any divs inside it. This is because I am working on Wordpress ecommerce where the images are dynamically generated and loaded when I added new product so the code would look like this:                            <div class="product">
   <img class="hover"/>
</div>   but I assume if I can correctly apply the <img> tag in absolute position, can the same result be achieved?

Comment: i just used divs for quick demo, you can indeed replace the inner div by img - should work exactly the same..

Comment: Thanks ptriek, what you did in supplying demo was really helpful for me, I had to modify code and css a little bit to achieve my objective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using toggleClass. have you tried $('[element]').show() and $('[element]').hide() ? or alternatively you can change the css from

```
display:none;
```

to

```
display:block;
```

Hope this will help